# Constness of STL containers and their elements - when to use const?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, constants

I have been overthinking (some may say underthinking, let's see what happens) the const-ness of STL containers and their elements.

I have been looking for a discussion of this, but the results have been surprisingly sparse. So I'm not necessarily looking for a definite answer here, I'd be just as happy with a discussion that gets the gears in my head moving again.

Let's say I have a class that keeps std::strings in a std::vector. My class is a dictionary that reads words from a dictionary file. They will never be changed. So it seems prudent to declare it as

```
std::vector<const std::string> m_myStrings;
```

However, I've read scattered comments that you shouldn't use const elements in a std::vector, since the elements need to be assignable.

Question:

- Are there cases when const elements are used in std::vector (excluding hacks etc)?
- Are const elements used in other containers? If so, which ones, and when?

I'm primarily talking about value types as elements here, not pointers.

Answer (score 4):

> My class is a dictionary that reads words from a dictionary file. They will never be changed.

Encapsulation can help here.

Have your class keep a `vector<string>`, but make it private.
Then add an accessor to your class that returns a `const vector<string> &`, and make the callers go through that.

The callers cannot change the vector, and `operator []` on the vector will hand them `const string &`, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: That's a good suggestion and it's pretty much what I decided to do. Since your solution requires making a copy of the whole vector, though, I'll probably provide an interface similar to this: `void iterateWords(std::function<void (const std::string&)> func);`: then callers can supply a lambda function to do whatever they want with the strings.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, for the reason you state.

Comment: Ok, a simple no is sufficient - at least it means that I've understood correctly. EDIT:  I really wish the compiler could catch this usage. I realize that there are reasons for it not to, though.

Comment: @Leander: Ok, a simple "Ok" is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

**In the context of `std::vector`, I don't think it makes sense to use a `const` qualifier with its template parameter because a `std::vector` is dynamic by nature and may be required to "move" in memory in order to "resize" itself.**

In the C++03 standard, `std::vector` is guaranteed stored in contiguous memory. This almost requires that `std::vector` be implemented with some form of an array. But how can we create a dynamic size-changing array? We cannot simply just "append" memory to the end of it--that would either require an additional node (and a linked list) or actually physically putting our additional entries at the end of the array, which would be either out-of-bounds or require us to just reserve more memory in the first place.

Thus, I would assume that `std::vector` would need to allocate an additional array, copy or move its members over to the end array, and then delete the old one.

It is not guaranteed that a move or copy assignment for every template-able object for a `std::vector` would *not* change the underlying object being moved or copied--it is considered good form to do add the `const` qualifier, but it is not required. Therefore, we cannot allow a `std::vector<const T>`.

Related: [How is C++ std::vector implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096571/how-is-c-stdvector-implemented)

Answer (score -1):

consider using

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>>
```

instead?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to avoid pointers here, even smart ones. :)

Comment: _"I'm primarily talking about value types as elements here, not pointers."_

Comment: In any case, this does not answer the question.