# Representing vectors using structures

Tags: c

I was recently asked to **represent a structure using a struct data type**.
As per my knowledge, a vector is represented as (10, 20, 30, 40 etc. )
It *appears* that it would be easier to access a **vector by an indexed data structure**, like an array.
But **I do not know how many members I would be needing in the struct data type**. Then how will I define the structure ?

Comment: you can try to create a dynamic array. allocate space for several elements, and when you fill it, create a new one, twice as big.

you can check this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096571/how-is-c-stdvector-implemented

Comment: If we are talking about vectors of a fixed dimension, say 2d, it is pretty natural to represent them as a structure of two fields `x` and `y`.

Comment: I guess the OP means how many members he'll be needing, instead of dimensions? ...could be that I'm wrong, but then I suggest that the OP clarifies this?

Comment: `vector` is kinda ambiguous term when it comes to programming..

Comment: Hmm, valid point there, perhaps the OP can rephrase the question a little bit, so we're sure that we're talking about the same thing here? Or not... my spideysense senses ambiguity!

Comment: When you say vector, are you talking about geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector is basically a dynamic array, meaning that the underlying type is a pointer to an array, each time you add something, the array increases by one. In a very basically this would lead to a costly copy each time this was done; this is way they mostly try to either predict the next size ( by doubling the amount of available slots) or allowing one to resize to a best-guess, which, if missed, will still result in doubling. Anyway, an insert (thus not at the end of the array) will still require a costly copy. This means that a vector will be interesting for random access reads of data, while not so for writes.

When you look at the O-complexity, you'll see that this now makes sense.

- Random access - constant O(1)
- Insertion or removal of elements at
  the end - amortized constant O(1)
- Insertion or removal of elements linear in distance to the end of the     vector O(n)

Knowing about the several data-containers is crucial to understand which one to pick under which circumstances. More often then not, I see programmers always using a vector (even the ones that are doing the job long enough to understand when to use which container).

**I'm sure this explanation will give you enough to implement the *real* thing ;-)**

sources:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Everything described could perfectly be done in C :-) ...I know the link is to C++ reference, as there is an implementation done in C++ STL; but the same characteristics still apply :-)

Comment: How do you know that is the kind of vector OP is after?

Comment: I agree that the question is ambiguous, the first time I read it, I believed, this is what he wanted... reading it again (and thanks to you), however, puts me in doubt :p I'm going to sit this one out and wait on clarification from the OP before I go ahead and delete this *answer* :-)

Answer (score 0):

In C99, you can define an FAM `struct`.

```
struct vector {
  size_t len;
  int vals[];
};
```

Then you can dynamically allocate instances of the struct, depending on the length you need.

```
struct vector* v = malloc(sizeof(struct vector) + (n * sizeof(v->vals[0]));
v->len = n;

for (int i = 0; i < v->len; i++)
  v->vals[i] = i;
```

A higher dimensional structure (e.g. matrix) is a bit trickier, but I'm not sure if you need that.

Comment: "Higher dimensions are a bit trickier, but I'm not sure if you need those." - this part makes no sense whatsoever. what you wrote already supports "higher" dimensions.

Comment: Not really, it allocates the memory, but it doesn't include accessing the values which would require modifying the `struct`.  For example, two dimensions or three dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean? The dimension of vector is it's length. You might get confused with matrices.

Comment: vals[0] is x, vals[1] is y, ... if not, I have no idea what your intention was with that struct.

Comment: That's what I was referring to, a higher dimensional structure.  I changed the wording

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to represent an int vector in C, I would use:

- a malloc'd array
- a variable tracking allocated size
- a variable tracking used length

It gives:

```
struct int_vector {
    int *arr;
    unsigned int len;
    unsigned int size;
};
```

Access to `arr` is *legal* for `0<=i<len`.

I would add some utilities:

```
int resize(struct int_vector *vec, unsigned int new_len) {
    if (new_len > vec->size) {
        void *p;
        unsigned int size = vec->size;
        while(new_len > size) size *= 2;
        *p = realloc(vec->arr, sizeof(int) * size);
        if (p == NULL) return 0; /* cannot realloc */
        vec->arr = p;
        vec->size = size;
    }
    vec->len = new_len;
}
```

You can then easily implement push and pop:

```
unsigned int push(int_vector *vec, int val) {
    if (resize(vec, vec->len + 1) == 0) return 0;
    vec->arr[vec->len -1] = ival;
    return vec->len;
}
int pop(int_vector *vec) {
    vec->len -= 1;
    return vec->arr[vec->len];
}
```

You could implement a truncate function to reduce the allocated size, but this is a simplistic but working example.

Unfortunately, as C has neither generics not templates, you would have to define a vector class for every and each type that you want to process...