# How is Stack implemented in STL?

Tags: c++, stl, stack, implementation

I came across this:

[Standard C++ Containers](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~riesbeck/programming/c++/stl-summary.html)

It triggered me the question, how are stacks implemented in STL?

I am looking for a description similar to:

[How is C++ std::vector implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096571/how-is-c-stdvector-implemented)

[What really is a deque in STL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl)

Comment: What in the description of the `stack` adapter at the link you provided is causing confusion? An alternative documentation on that adapter [can be found **here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), and I highly recc you bookmark that site. It is outstanding as a C++ reference, one of the very best imho.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`stack` is an adapter which uses another container for the underlying storage, and links the functions `push`, `pop`, `emplace` etc. to the relevant functions in the underlying container.

By default, `std::stack` uses `std::deque` as underlying container. But you can specify your own, e.g. `std::stack<T, std::vector<T>> s;`.

For more details about this, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Answer (score 5):

`std::stack` has a template parameter `Container`, which is required to be a container that can store elements of type `T` (that is to say, the type of the elements of the stack). This container is required to have `back()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()` functions, and the standard containers `vector`, `deque` and `list` all satisfy the requirements.

So, whichever container type the user specifies, the resulting instantiation of `std::stack` is a class which:

- has a data member of type `Container<T>` (or something very similar if not literally a data member. I suppose it could probably be a private base class).
- calls `push_back()` on the container whenever you call `push()` on the stack.
- calls `pop_back()` on the container whenever you call `pop()` on the stack.
- and so on.

Loosely speaking, `std::stack<T>` is an object that wraps up an instance of `std::deque<T>`, and hides most of `deque`'s functionality in order to present a simpler interface *solely* for use as a last-in-first-out (LIFO) queue. Similarly `std::queue` presents a FIFO queue.