# Visual Studio 2015 and static code analyzer warning C28182 on operator new array

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2015, initialization, static-code-analysis

We are using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 + Cumulative Servicing Release.

The following static code analyzer warning appears always at a specific situation:

```
operatornew.cpp(5): warning C28182: Dereferencing NULL pointer. 'a' contains the same NULL value as 'Temp_value_#2119' did.
```

1. A pointer is dereferenced
2. That pointer was allocated using array operator new
3. and zero-initialization

See MWE here:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int, char**)
{
  int * a = new int[400]();
  a[0] = 1;

  int * b = new int[400];
  b[0] = 1;

  std::cout << a[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << b[0] << std::endl;

  delete[] a;
  delete[] b;
  return 0;
}
```

SCA warning is emmited at line 5.

But when derefencing pointer 'b' - which does not use zero-initialitation - there is no warning.

The warning says, that pointer 'a' is NULL when allocation failed. I would rather expect an exception on allocation failure. So I think pointer 'a' is never NULL in this example.

Is this static code analyzer warning a false positive?

Is there an exception std::bad_alloc when using array operator new with zero-initialization (and MSVC15+Update3)?

Comment: False positive for me. As a note using `std::vector` in that case should avoid that warning, and you may get rid of manual `delete[]`.

Comment: One could use a smart pointer as well and the warning mysteriously vanishes. But our code base is huge and changing all occurences into smart pointers takes ages.

Comment: It is a false positive. Try to use a more progressive code analyzer, for example, PVS-Studio.

Comment: We have PVS-Studio now and it performs really great in static code analysis.

Comment: does visual studio 2022 uses a code analyzer better than the code analyzer of visual studio 2015  ( So that is the reason why when i try to compile ( compile and run )  the code which is wrote in the question ( using visual studio 2022  ) the warning ( C28182 )  does not appear ) ? @Jarod42

Comment: @FadyHany: New versions (try to) does improvement, so I would say yes. If that particular warning has been improved, I don't know. (Seems yes, as you cannot reproduce the issue :-) ).

Comment: when you said  "  False positive for me. As a note using `std::vector` in that case should avoid that warning, and you may get rid of manual delete[]. " you said " and you may get rid of manual delete[]. "   you mean that when we use `std::vector` we do not have to write ( by ourselves )  in our code  delete[] but it was written in the code of built-in `std::vector`  . So we still use ( new and delete[] ) even if we use `std::vector`      , right  ? @Jarod42

Comment: @FadyHany: `std::vector` will do the allocation under the wood (It would not call `new int[400]` but would allocate enough place and would do *placement-new* for the different `int`, but that is just detail).

Comment: Can you explain this " (It would not call new int[400] but would allocate enough place and would do placement-new for the different int, but that is just detail). " ?  and does  " under the wood " mean  ( secretly ) ? @Jarod42

Comment: @FadyHany: Look at [how-is-c-stdvector-implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096571/how-is-c-stdvector-implemented) or some `std::vector` implementations for details.

Comment: does " under the wood " mean ( secretly ) ? @Jarod42

Comment: Typo -> *"Under the hood"*. *"secret"* has for me a meaning of hiding and should not be known, whereas I would mean more something that is a details/internal of implementation.

Comment: in the link you mentioned the second answer said " If your implementation simply ended up doing new Foo[10] then you'd just have constructed 10 instances of Foo.
Instead it uses its allocator to allocate and deallocate raw memory (without constructing objects) " but when i try to compile ( compile and run ) this code : class test {
public:
 test() {
  cout << "test" << endl;
 }
};

int main() {
    vector<test>X(10);
    return 0;
}
 the output : 
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
test

Comment: ?????? @jarod42

Comment: @FadyHany: Answers from links are indeed not good quality IMO :-( . `std::vector` has `reserve`, and so `reserve(10);` won't call `new T[10];`, but something like `new std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>[10]`, and doing *placement new* when needed.

Comment: std::vector uses std::allocator to allocate the memory and in this link : https://cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/allocate/  
 In the standard default allocator, the block of storage is allocated using ::operator new one or more times, and throws bad_alloc if it cannot allocate the total amount of storage requested.
So now are you convinced of my opinion ? @Jarod42

Comment: ?????? @jarod42

Comment: @FadyHany: `new Test[42]` allocates, but also call constructors of `Test` (so not compatible with `reserve`). `allocator<Test>{}.allocate(42)` would just allocate (it would allocate a aligned buffer of `char`/`byte` ) and **not** call constructor (of `Test`); you need [`construct`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/construct/) (which is basically a placement new) afterward.

Comment: the allocator uses ::operator new and it does not call the constructors  like this code :
#include <new>
using namespace std;
class test { 
public: test() { 
 cout << "test" << endl; 
} 
}; 
int main() {
 test* p = (test*)::operator new (sizeof(test));
 return 0; 
}

@Jarod42

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246201/discussion-between-jarod42-and-fady-hany).