# Converting into multidimensional std::array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

```
int data[][4] = { {1,2,3,4}, {9,8,7,6}, {2,4,6,8} };
```

I want to convert this into multidimensional std::array

```
array< array<int,4>, 3 > stddata = { {1,2,3,4}, {9,8,7,6}, {2,4,6,8} };
```

like this.
But error occur in this code. Why does this error occur? and how can I change reset part  { {1,2,3,4}, {9,8,7,6}, {2,4,6,8} } to  { , } numbers.

Comment: Just add a couple of `{` ... `}` so you get `std::array<std::array<int,4>, 3> stddata = {{ {1,2,3,4}, {9,8,7,6}, {2,4,6,8} }};`

Comment: what is most uniform about initialization is that if it doesnt work: add more brackets ;)

Comment: when your question is about a compiler error, please include the compiler error in the question

Comment: The second part of your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "{ , } numbers"?

Answer (score -3):

Update:
Here is code using `std::array`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::array< std::array<int, 4>, 3> stddata = {{{1,2,3,4}, {9,8,7,6}, {2,4,6,8}}};
    return 0;
}
```

If the usecase is to add / remove more values during the lifetime of the container, we can use `std::vector`. Here is sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector< std::vector<int>> stddata = { {1,2,3,4}, {9,8,7,6}, {2,4,6,8} };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. Data in `array< array<int,4>, 3 >` is stored continuously in memory. For `std::vector< std::vector<int>>` the data is likely not stored continuously. `std::array` might allow more optimizations, has less memory allocations, …

Comment: As per my understanding, `std::vector` is also implemented using underlying array. ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096571/how-is-c-stdvector-implemented
I have also provided the `std::array` implementation for the same with update.

Comment: why would you prefer `std::vector`? When you give a suggestion like that you need to explain "why" otherwise the suggestion is either useless or leads to cargo cult. I also don't agree btw

Comment: You're using `using namespace std;` that by itself is a thing that should be avoided, but you're also writing `std::` before the declaration of the vectors and arrays. Replace `using namespace std;` with `using std::vector` or `using std::array` and don't write `std::` before them.

Comment: @MitalVora a `std::vector` needs at least two allocations one for `std::vector` itself and one for the data that is stored. `std::array` encloses the data withing the `std::array` type itself. For nested `std:array`s you have only one memory allocation, and continuous memory. So for this example, you have 5 memory allocations for the `std::vector` version and only one for the `std::array` version.

Comment: The only reason I prefer using vector is to dynamically add/remove more values to the container. I find it useful. I agree it would have multiple allocations and performance wise, it takes more time for initialization.

Comment: @MitalVora if that is your requirement then sure. But if you want to e.g. represent a NxM matrix, you don't want and need to use `std::vector`.